# Complex analysis, Ian Stewart Exercise 4.7.5: Proving $\sqrt{z}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{x\leq0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, branch-cuts

This is exercise 4.7.5 in Ian Stewart's "Complex Analysis
(The Hitch Hiker’s Guide to the Plane)":

Let $C_{\pi} =\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z\neq x\in\mathbb{R},x\leq0\}$ be the 'cut plane' with the negative real axis removed. Define $r : C_{\pi} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $(r(z))^2 = z$ and $\operatorname{Re} r(z) > 0$. Prove that $r$ is continuous on $C_{\pi}$.

May I ask how can I prove it without using theorems like Inverse function theorem from multivariable calculus?

Comment: Use $z_1-z_2=r(z_1)^2-r(z_2)^2=(r(z_1)+r(z_2))(r(z_1)-r(z_2))$ to bound $|r(z_1)-r(z_2)|$ by a multiple of $|z_1-z_2|$, when $z_2$ is close enough to $z_1$ such that $r(z_1)+r(z_2)$ is away from $0$.

Comment: Your definition of C_π makes it equal to the imaginary numbers {xi  |  x ∈ ℝ}, not the "cut plane".

Comment: @DanAsimov Thanks, I'll edit the title of my question.

Comment: @NDB But how to bound $r(z_1)+r(z_2)$ away from 0 without knowing the values of $r(z_1)$ and $r(z_2)$?

Comment: HIH: I think the question itself needs to be edited.  (It seems far more likely that Stewart would ask the question about continuity on the cut plane than on the imaginary axis.)

Comment: @DanAsimov I'm terribly sorry, I made a wrong latex code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $z\in\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$, then$$r(z)=\frac{\sqrt{\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|}}{\sqrt2}+\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)}{\sqrt2\sqrt{\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|}}i,\label{a}\tag1$$since:

1. $\displaystyle\left(\frac{\sqrt{\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|}}{\sqrt2}+\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)}{\sqrt2\sqrt{\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|}}i\right)^2=z$;
2. $\displaystyle\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|}}{\sqrt2}+\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)}{\sqrt2\sqrt{\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|}}i\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|}}{\sqrt2}>0$.

It is clear that the RHS of \eqref{a} is continuous.

Comment: Thanks! I assume it would be very difficult to prove it without knowing the explicit expression of $r(z)$ right?

Comment: Well, you could also show that the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\{z\in\Bbb C\mid\operatorname{Re}z>0\}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]\\z&\mapsto&z^2\end{array}$$is both an open map and a bijection. Therefore, its inverse (which is $r$) is continuous.